# open swf files of different framerate with a button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame-rate

I have a 6 swf files. After the endo of each swf animation a button appears and when clicked it opens the next swf file. However, 3 of the swf files have a different framerate. 3 of them work at 24fps and 3 of them at 48fps. When I play the swf files, all the animations work at the same framerate (24fps). Is there a way to combine and open both files each one at its own framerate?
Here i attach you the code i use to open the files when pressing the button

Thank you very much !

```
stop();
//This creates a new instance of the loader object and adds it to the stage.

var my_Loader:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(my_Loader);

 //This creates a new instance of the URLRequest object that contains the path   
//to the external swf. The load method then loads the SWF file into the loader
//object.
var my_url:URLRequest=new URLRequest("Sinus for adults.swf");
my_Loader.load(my_url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling gives this simple response :

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?284196-merging-two-swf-movies-with-different-FPS

I haven't tried it though but as per my knowledge it should work.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not possible.

What you could do though is advance frames using a timer, but if you have multiple levels of MovieClips with timelines, you'd have to advance them individually. You'd also miss out on any code execution especially stop and play as you'd be overriding them.